# Pull the data on a daily basis

Tags: amazon-redshift, aws-glue

I have data in my redshift cluster, What is the best way to pull the data on daily basis from redshift and create a new new table YY in redshift basis of few sql queries.

Like we have a table XX in redshift and i want to create a table in redshift from pull the top 10 rows from table XX

Create table YY as Select top 10 * from XX

Comment: there is no in built scheduler in Redshift, you can automate using a small linux server on ec2 using crontab, or airflow if your requirement is complex.

Comment: Hey Jon, Thank you for your reply. Can we do this through Lambda?

Comment: lambda is OK except for the maximum duration (15 mins), and it is a bit more difficult to catch issues.

Comment: Thank you. I am unable to link Lambda function with Redshift. Is there any video or documents available where i can reach out and see what are functionality they use to connect lambda function with redshift?

Answer (score 0):

Using `AWS-Glue` you could schedule the Job and then write the the scripts code to do specific things. `AWS-glue` code could be triggered on following 3 type of events, in your case I think #1 is applicable.

1. A trigger that is based on a cron schedule.
2. A trigger that is event-based; for example, the successful completion of another job can start an AWS Glue job.
3. A trigger that starts a job on demand.

For your case in my opinion, [this](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/glue/latest/dg/aws-glue-programming-python-libraries.html) should be more applicable.

I hope this should give you some pointers.